# MySQL: how to delete a row in a table after inserting one in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables tbA and tbB, data always arrive to tbA, but I have a trigger that sends some rows to tbB, I want those rows to be deleted from tbA as I only want them on tbB, at first I tried with a trigger in tbA (AFTER INSERT), something like this:

**BEGIN**

```
 IF (new.condition="a") THEN INSERT INTO tbB (id,condition,nA,nB) 
 VALUES(new.id,new.condition,new.nA,new.nB) DELETE FROM tbA WHERE
 id=new.id END IF
```

**END**

It copies the data into tbB but it doesn't delete it from tbA, I also tried to put the DELETE statement in a trigger on the tbB table but it doesn't work either

**BEGIN**

```
 DELETE FROM tbA WHERE id=new.id
```

**END**

can someone please help me or give me hints on how to do that?

Comment: just wondering, maybe you could add a flag column and another trigger in tbB, so if the change come with that flag set, you could trigger the removal from tbA

Comment: Further research showed me that you can't delete new registers with a trigger, my approach after that was to simply run a cleaning routine every week when the load was not high.